# I want to prevent the registration of the parent bean when the child bean is registered

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

UserService.java

```
@Service
class UserService {
    //target test method
    public int getUser(){
        DbUtil.getMapper(UserMapper.java);
    }
}
```

DbUtil.java

```
class DbUtil {
    
    static DbService dbService;
    
    public static <T> T getMapper(Class<T> clazz){
        if(dbService == null){
            dbService = ((DbService)) ApplicationContextManager.getBean("dbService");
        }
        return dbService.getSqlSessionTemplate().getMapper(clazz);
    }
}
```

DbService.java

```
@Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration configuration;
    
    @Autowired
    private SecondConfiguration secondConfiguration;
    
    public SqlSessionTemplate getSqlSessionTemplate(){
        //complecated logic...
    }
```

FakeDbService.java

```
@Service
class FakeDbService extends DbService {
    public SqlSessionTemplate getSqlSessionTemplate(){
        // simple logic ...
    }
}
```

TestConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@Import(FakeDbService.class)
class TestConfiguration {
    
}
```

Test.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Test
    public void userServiceTest(){
        userService.getUser();
    }
}
```

My purpose is to test `getUser` method in `UserService`.
`DbUtil` class import `DbService` bean using `ApplicationContextManager.getBean("dbService")`.
Because `DbService` class has a lot of dependencies and requires additional dependencies, I tried to create a `FakeDbService` that overrides only the necessary methods and inherits `DbService`.
But it didn't work.

When creating the spring container, not only the `FakeDbService` bean was registered, but also the parent class, the `DbService` bean.
There was an error in not finding bean because spring container was executed without adding dependence on `DbService`.
I want to prevent the generation of `DbService` which is a parent class during spring container generation.

Wouldn't it be possible to test it like this?
Or is there another way to test in the above structure? (However, I can't modify source of `DbService` and `DbUtil`)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why does `DbUtil` exist? Why not just put those methods on `DbService` and inject `DbService` where you use `DbUtil`?

Comment: You've got code which has not been written with testing in mind. Fix that by refactoring the code rather than jumping through hoops to try and test it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Spring component which converts `DbUtil` to a non-static component:

```
@Component
class DbUtilComponent {
    public <T> T getMapper(Class<T> clazz) { return DbUtil.getMapper(clazz); }
    ...
}
```

Inject this into `UserService`:

```
@Service
class UserService {
    private final DbUtilComponent dbUtilComponent;

    public UserService(DbUtilComponent dbUtilComponent) {
        this.dbUtilComponent = dbUtilComponent;
    }
    //target test method
    public int getUser(){
        dbUtilComponent.getMapper(UserMapper.java);
    }
}
```

Then just use Mockito for your test, don't even start a Spring context.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {
    @Mock
    private DbUtilComponent dbUtilComponent;
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Test
    public void userServiceTest(){
        when(dbUtilComponent.getMapper(UserMapper.class)).thenReturn(...);
        userService.getUser();
    }
}
```